# To hide and display DIV if Radio button is checked

Tags: jquery, css

I want to display DIV having class 'checkboxClass' only if radio button is checked that is inside DIV having class 'radioClass'.

My current code is displaying all the DIV elements that have class 'checkboxClass' when any Radio button is checked.

If radio button inside specific 'mainSection' class is checked then I want to display all DIV that have class 'checkboxClass' inside that 'mainSection' otherwise it should be hidden.

```js
$('.radioClass input:radio').bind('click touch', function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $('.checkboxClass').css("display", "block");
  } else {
    $('.checkboxClass').css("display", "none");
  }
});
```

```css
.checkboxClass {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="mainSection" style="border:solid 1px #aaa">
  <div class="radioClass">
    <input type="radio" name="xyz" value="xyz">
  </div>
  <div class="checkboxClass"><input type="checkbox"></div>
  <div class="checkboxClass"><input type="checkbox"></div>
  <div class="checkboxClass"><input type="checkbox"></div>
</div>
<br />
<div class="mainSection" style="border:solid 1px #aaa">
  <div class="radioClass">
    <input type="radio" name="xyz" value="xyz">
  </div>
  <div class="checkboxClass"><input type="checkbox"></div>
  <div class="checkboxClass"><input type="checkbox"></div>
  <div class="checkboxClass"><input type="checkbox"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, Use `parent child` selector `$('.mainSection .radioClass input:radio')`

And to find specific check-boxes traverse upto the parents `$(this).parents('.mainSection').find('.checkboxClass')`

```js
$('.mainSection .radioClass input:radio').bind('click touch', function () {
  
  $('.checkboxClass').css("display", "none");
            if($(this).is(":checked"))
            {
                $(this).parents('.mainSection').find('.checkboxClass').css("display", "block");
            }
            else {
                $(this).parents('.mainSection').find('.checkboxClass').css("display", "none");
}
        });
```

```css
.checkboxClass
{

   display:none; 

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mainSection">

<div class="radioClass">
<input type="radio" name="xyz" value="xyz" >Number</div>
<div class="checkboxClass">123</div>
<div class="checkboxClass">456</div>
<div class="checkboxClass">789</div>


</div>

<div class="mainSection">

<div class="radioClass">
<input type="radio" name="xyz" value="xyz" >Characters
</div>

<div class="checkboxClass">ABC</div>
<div class="checkboxClass">XYZ</div>
<div class="checkboxClass">PQR</div>

</div>
```

Comment: The changed selector is still unnecessary. But at least there is now an explanation of the real fix ;)

Comment: @Andreas now reverse your downvote. I just shown him a way to achieve it. There can be multiple ways to do the same

Comment: @Loading.. Thank you. But if 'Character' is selected once then Corresponding Character will shown, but after that if I select 'Number' then I want to hide displayed characters . Is it possible?

Comment: You need to hide `$('.checkboxClass').css("display", "none");` first when some radio is clicked, check my updated example. and let me know if you still find any problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to travese up to `mainSection` using 
[`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) then target `checkboxClass` and perform the desired operation.

```
$('.radioClass input:radio').bind('click touch', function() {
     var mainSection = $(this).closest('.mainSection');
     mainSection.find('.checkboxClass').toggle(this.checked);

     //Hide others
     $('.mainSection').not(mainSection).find('.checkboxClass').hide();
});
```

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.radioClass input:radio').on('click', function() {
    var mainSection = $(this).closest('.mainSection');
    mainSection.find('.checkboxClass').toggle(this.checked);
    
    //Hide others
    $('.mainSection').not(mainSection).find('.checkboxClass').hide();
  });
})
```

```css
.checkboxClass {display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mainSection">
  <div class="radioClass">
    <input type="radio" name="xyz" value="1">1
  </div>
  <div class="checkboxClass">checkboxClass in 1</div>
  <div class="checkboxClass">checkboxClass in 1</div>
  <div class="checkboxClass">checkboxClass in 1</div>
</div>

<div class="mainSection">
  <div class="radioClass">
    <input type="radio" name="xyz" value="2">2
  </div>
  <div class="checkboxClass">checkboxClass in 2</div>
  <div class="checkboxClass">checkboxClass in 2</div>
  <div class="checkboxClass">checkboxClass in 2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) and [find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) method

```
 $('.radioClass input:radio').bind('click touch', function () {
            if($(this).is(":checked"))
            {    
                $(this).closest('.mainSection').find('.checkboxClass').css("display", "block");
            }
            else {
                $(this).closest('.mainSection').find('.checkboxClass').css("display", "none");
}
        });
```

Or use [siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) of [parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)

```
 $('.radioClass input:radio').bind('click touch', function () {
            if($(this).is(":checked"))
            {    
                $(this).parent().siblings('.checkboxClass').css("display", "block");
            }
            else {
                $(this).parent().siblings('.checkboxClass').css("display", "none");
}
        });
```